# overcoming the 1664 column list limit in postgres by joining multiple partial selects in memory?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Postgres limits number of columns in a `SELECT` statement to 1664, otherwise the "**target lists can have at most 1664 entries**" error.

In our app, we dynamically create `SELECT` statements on the fly and may get joins with columns numbers exceeding this limit.

My idea was to check the number of columns in the resulting `SELECT` statement and, if they exceed e.g. 1000, split the `SELECT` STATEMENT into several ones with the same `WHERE` clauses but different lists of columns to be selected and then join the results of multiple selects in-memory,e.g.

1. select first 1000 columns
2. select second 1000 columns ... as necessary

But in order to join the partial result sets, each should contain some unique row id to enable a join.

So we introduced

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() AS ROW_NUM OVER (GROUP BY root.id), <1st 1000 column names> 
FROM root 
  JOIN ..
```

but that won't work correctly since some joins represent one-to-many relations, and a single root table item may be related to multiple child items.

Is it possible to solve this problem at all?

Comment: What is forcing you to use the giant selects?

Comment: Are all those columns of the same data type? Would it be OK to convert them all to varchar?

Comment: you can concat many columns to less with some delimiter?..

Comment: Sounds like you're getting things the wrong way round. What you're selecting as columns should be rows

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). A workaround I can think of: return a single JSON column that contains as many keys as you need "columns"